# Using $this when not in object context static function

Tags: php

This is my static function to generate a random string:

```
    public static function generateCode($salt)
    {
        $this->generate = substr(hash('sha512', $salt), 0, 15);
        return $this->generate;
    }
```

And that's how I use it:

```
            $this->insert->execute(array(
            ":username" => $username,
            "generated_code" => self::generateCode($email)
            ));
```

I have declared the property:

```
    protected $generate;
```

Getting this error:

```
Fatal error: Using $this when not in object context in C:\xampp\htdocs\drip\class\users.class.php on line 154
```

**Line 154:**

```
        $this->generate = substr(hash('sha512', $salt), 0, 15);
```

***What's wrong with this? Why is it giving me that error?***

Comment: `$this` does not exist in static functions. They only exist in class context, there is no object instance

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Static methods do not belong to the instance of an object, $this relates to the instance...

In this instance I don't think you need anything other than to simply return the result of the hash (candidate for a lambda expression maybe?)

```
public static function generateCode($salt)
{
    return substr(hash('sha512', $salt), 0, 15);
}
```

Comment: @user2326532 sure, why not?

Comment: @user2326532 The access level of a method is separate from whether or not it is class or instance level.

Answer (score 4):

A `static` function means it is 'bound' to the class, not each instance (object). Call it like this:

```
  ClassName::generateCode($email);
```

Also, you cannot use object members in static functions. Make your `$generate` member also `static`, and refer to it as:

```
  ClassName::$generate
```

Comment: It is in the same class, therefore I called it self::, I've read that you've to use self:: if its in the same class, However, It did not fix the error.

Comment: That's when the member is static, not the method.

Comment: You can use `self::` or `static::` when accessing internal class (static) methods, that is correct.

Comment: @Orbling yes, but you cannot use `self::` or `static::` on non-static members.

Comment: @BartFriederichs: Aye, only static methods and properties.  It's helpful to think of those two as the class level versions of `$this`.

Answer (score 0):

Inside your function you should use self instead of $this because the function is declared static.

Declare your member $generate as  static, else it would not work.